# Distorted tick labels with matplotlib.animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

With more recent versions of matplotlib I'm getting distorted labels on animated plots. Is anybody else getting this? Am I doing something wrong?

Minimum working example:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython import display

print(matplotlib.__version__)

# Make a random array of data to plot

r = np.random.rand(10,100,100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,10))

# Initiate Plot

plot = ax.pcolormesh(range(0,100), 
                    range(0,100), 
                    r[0], 
                    cmap='RdBu')

cb = fig.colorbar(plot)
cb.set_label('Temperature')

def animate(frame):
    
    C = r[frame][:-1,:-1]
    
    plot.set_array(C)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                              animate,
                             frames= range(0,r.shape[0]),
                             )    

video = ani.to_html5_video()
html = display.HTML(video)
display.display(html)
plt.close()
```

My labels seem like they're being placed many times (although this bug persists even when the animation only has two frames), and they appear like this:

[image]

This behaviour does not occur if I comment out all the lines below the `ax.pcolormesh...` which creates static plot that looks fine.

I'm on matplotlib 3.3.2

Comment: This is a known bug with the inline backend unfortunately: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/19040

Comment: I'd suggest using the notebook backend (%matplotlib notebook only works with jupyter notebook) or using ipympl backend https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl (works in notebook and lab)

Comment: as a workaroud you can downgrade your maptlotlib to version 3.2

Comment: Great, thanks! 

Can confirm this works for me, and also that saved animations from the notebook are bug-free this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at the github link, and found this response from billbrod:

> I've had this same issue (I was comparing v3.3.0 and v3.1.0, running in Jupyter lab), and found out that rcParams['savefig.facecolor'] was 'auto'. Changing it back to 'white' (as had been the case in v3.1.0) fixed the issue.

This translates to:

```
plt.rcParams['savefig.facecolor'] = 'white'
```

Worked like a charm for me!